# how to properly let a thread terminate by himself?

Tags: delphi

I have this thread :

```
 TWorkerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FSignal: TEvent;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

constructor TWorkerThread.Create;
begin
  FSignal := TEvent.Create(nil, false{ManualReset}, false, '');
  inherited Create(false{CreateSuspended});
end;

destructor TWorkerThread.Destroy;
begin
  Terminate;
  FSignal.SetEvent;
  WaitFor;
  AlFreeAndNil(FSignal);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do begin

    ....

    fSignal.WaitFor(INFINITE);

  end;
end;
```

OK, so now "sometime" in my main thread I want to free this thread, but i not want to wait that it's finish (don't want to block the main thread), so i can't call at this moment `MyThread.free` the will do a `waitFor`

i want to do somethink like this

```
    fMyWorkerThreads[i].FreeOnTerminate := True;
    fMyWorkerThreads[i].Terminate;
    fMyWorkerThreads[i].Signal.SetEvent;
    fMyWorkerThreads[i] := nil;
```

but this could make an error, imagine that when i call `fMyWorkerThreads[i].Terminate;` if I m very of the very unlucky and `fMyWorkerThreads[i]` is freed before to arrive to the line `fMyWorkerThreads[i].Signal.SetEvent;` i will have access violation ?

so how can i do? if i call `fMyWorkerThreads[i].Signal.SetEvent;` before `fMyWorkerThreads[i].Terminate;` i can also be unlucky of the unlucky and `fMyWorkerThreads[i].execute` make a round trip an arrive again to `fSignal.WaitFor(INFINITE);` before the instruction `fMyWorkerThreads[i].Terminate;`

Comment: Remove the first three lines in "Destroy". In main thread, forget "freeonterminate", "terminate" the thread, signal the event and then "free".

Comment: Freeonterminate is for you don't wanna hear about the thread anymore. If you have a reference to it, that's not the case.

Comment: Long story short, from the exact moment you call `FreeOnTerminate`, you should never ever ever even think about accessing the thread class anymore.

Comment: yes i agree that at the moment I call freeonTerminate := true i should forget about the thread :( i was hopping to find some way out but seam their is no way out ...

Answer (score -2):

The simple solution is not to use the standard `Terminate`. **Warning**: the code below is for your abstract question. And this is not a template for all cases.

```
interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SyncObjs;

type

  TTestThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FSignal: TEvent;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure CustomTerminate;
  end;

procedure Test1();
procedure Test2();

implementation

uses
  Winapi.Windows;

{ TTestThread }

constructor TTestThread.Create;
begin
  FSignal := TEvent.Create(nil, True{must be true}, False, '');
  inherited Create(False);
end;

procedure TTestThread.CustomTerminate;
begin
  FSignal.SetEvent();
end;

destructor TTestThread.Destroy;
begin
  CustomTerminate();

  // this is standart way, but it will be much better to use one more own event
  if not FreeOnTerminate then // without this check, will be deadlock
    WaitFor;

  FSignal.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTestThread.Execute;
begin
  // TEvent.WaitFor can end with an error. Read docs before use
  while FSignal.WaitFor(0) = TWaitResult.wrTimeout do begin
    FSignal.WaitFor(INFINITE);
  end;
end;

procedure Test1();
var
  T: TTestThread;
begin
  T := TTestThread.Create();
  try
    Sleep(2000);
  finally
    T.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure Test2();
var
  T: TTestThread;
begin
  T := TTestThread.Create();
  Sleep(2000);
  T.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  T.CustomTerminate;
end;
```

**But...**

You want to use a `FreeOnTerminate` outside the thread class, it can be convenient, but it introduces dangerous confusion. It is much better to use this flag in the constructor or not to use it at all. Here are more reasons why you should not use it:

- If you will be are not very careful, a forgotten thread can use data that should not
- if thread not stopping before application stopping, you can get some bad errors
- If the thread unexpectedly terminates (for example by exception) and after that you set `FreeOnTerminate`, then the thread object will not be destroyed.

IMHO: I do not advise using `FreeOnTerminate`.

**Upd:**
Solution with standart `Terminate`.

```
interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SyncObjs;

type

  TTestThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FSignal: TEvent;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.Windows;

{ TTestThread }

constructor TTestThread.Create;
begin
  FSignal := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
  inherited Create(False);
end;

destructor TTestThread.Destroy;
begin
  Terminate;

  // this is standart way, but it will be much better to use one more own event
  if not FreeOnTerminate then // without this check, will be deadlock
    WaitFor;

  FSignal.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTestThread.Execute;
begin
  // TEvent.WaitFor can end with an error. Read docs before use
  while FSignal.WaitFor(0) = TWaitResult.wrTimeout do begin
    FSignal.WaitFor(INFINITE);
  end;
end;

procedure TTestThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  FSignal.SetEvent();
end;

end;
```

Comment: You don't need `CustomTerminate()` at all. You can override `TThread.TerminatedSet()` instead to call `FSignal.SetEvent()`, then the event will be signaled automatically whenever `Terminate()` is called.

Comment: Amazing that this has been up voted. A number of errors and confusion here. The worst being setting FreeOnTerminate to True and subsequently accessing the thread through a reference.

Comment: @David Heffernan `subsequently accessing the thread through a reference`  What do you mean by that?

Comment: @David Heffernan I can not understand, why i can not use a refernce after setting a flag in this particular example

Comment: Because the object might have been destroyed

Comment: @David Heffernan Ok, i understand that you mean. I wrote this code as example. I know that there are many reasons why this code breaks down.

Comment: Good. You agree with my voting then.